# Why I lost the days from 2-6? It shows always days in a 7 days turn

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS(DATE, - CASE WHEN COUNTRYCODE='TH' 
AND DATE >= (CURRENT_DATE+1)
THEN 6516 ELSE 0 END) 
, 'day' ) as RDATE,
```

Comment: Sample data, expected and actual results would be helpful, it's unclear what  you are asking or what issue you have. [The documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions255.htm) is for `trunc` to return the starting day of the week with the `day` format model. So what are you trying to do - get to the start of the day (i.e. set time to midnight), rather than the start of the week?

Answer (score 1):

When you use TRUNC(DATE,'DAY') then it expected to display the date based on first day of week. Please refer link [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) where you can see below. That is the reason, you loose 2 to 6 days.

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'DAY')
Result: '17-AUG-03'
```